# Mysql Select Statement using OR

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new at select statements, so can someone assist me with the PHP query I'm trying to accomplish.

There are 5 columns in MYSQL table **(Partner_Name, Partner_Name2, Partner_Name3, Partner_Name4, Partner_Name5)**

My current PHP statement looks like this.

```
$query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients  WHERE tblclients.partner_name =  'Store_1' AND tblclients.package =  'standard' AND tblclients.category = 'all' LIMIT 0, 9");
```

My goal is to have something like this...

```
$query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients WHERE tblclients.partner_name =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_2 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_3 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_4 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_5 =  'Store_1' AND tblclients.package =  'standard' AND tblclients.category = 'all'  0, 9");
```

It doesn't appear to be returning results in the way I expected. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Can you give me an example how I would go about it? Thanks!

Comment: just put parenthesis `(... OR ... OR ...)` in all of your OR clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw, you forgot to add LIMIT on the 2nd query.

> $query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' AND tblclients.category = 'all' AND (tblclients.partner_name =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_2 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_3 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_4 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_5 =  'Store_1') LIMIT 0, 9");

And if you have time, maybe have table optimizations so that your query will be a bit nicer and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' AND tblclients.category = 'all' AND (tblclients.partner_name =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_2 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_3 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_4 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_5 =  'Store_1')  0, 9");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients WHERE (tblclients.partner_name =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_2 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_3 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_4 =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_5 =  'Store_1') AND tblclients.package =  'standard' AND tblclients.category = 'all'  limit 0,9 ");

Answer (score 0):

just use (... OR ...), in your case:

> AND (tblclients.partner_name =  'Store_1' OR tblclients.partner_name_2
> =  'Store_1' OR ...)

Comment: Your answer is good but please elaborate how its better then the accepted answer. The Original poster and the accepted answer have `OR` in their codes as well.